# tikzpicture writing below bent arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get text below the bent arrows but I get errors.

This works (only text below the straight arrow):

```
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) -- node[below, color=black] {$N$ inputs} (input);
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=135, out = 45] (input);
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=90, out = 90] (input);
```

But this doesn't (I want "..." below the second bent arrow):

```
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) -- node[below, color=black] {$N$ inputs} (input);
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=135, out = 45] -- node[below, color=black] {...} (input);
\path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=90, out = 90] (input);
```

I'm working on overleaf. I have two nodes:

```
\node [cloud, node distance = 4.5cm] (batchinput) {Batch};
\node [cloud, right of=batchinput, node distance = 4.5cm] (input) {Input};
```

And everything is wrapped under:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, node distance = 3.5cm, auto]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Whole code is:

```
    \usepackage{tikz}   
    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,
        text width=8em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
        text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{blockd} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20,
        text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=green!20, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=2em]
    \tikzstyle{connector} = [draw, circle,fill=white!20, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=2em]
    % Code
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, node distance = 3.5cm, auto]
        \node [cloud, node distance = 4.5cm] (batchinput) {Batch};
        \node [cloud, right of=batchinput, node distance = 4.5cm] (input) {Input};
        \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) -- node[below, color=black] {$N$ inputs} (input);
        \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=135, out = 45] -- node[below, color=black] {...} (input);
        \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=90, out = 90] (input);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not only show code snippets, show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your error ...

Comment: It's just putting them together. But I'll edit my post, sorry. EDIT: actually you were right, i missed some definitions in my minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer, I wasn't supposed the repeat `--`.

The code, fixed, is the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}   
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,
    text width=8em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
    text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{blockd} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20,
    text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=green!20, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{connector} = [draw, circle,fill=white!20, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=2em]
% Code
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, node distance = 3.5cm, auto]
    \node [cloud, node distance = 4.5cm] (batchinput) {Batch};
    \node [cloud, right of=batchinput, node distance = 4.5cm] (input) {Input};
    \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) -- node[below, color=black] {$N$ inputs} (input);
    \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=135, out = 45] node[below, color=black] {...} (input);
    \path [line,dashed] (batchinput) to[bend right, looseness=0.5, in=90, out = 90] (input);
\end{tikzpicture}
```